# React-Native/Firebase /I'm having a problem with react native firebase version migration

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

My code is as follows, what am I doing wrong? I go to a web service and try to provide instant updates.

I had no problem using firebase v6 after the update I got this problem. I studied the documentation but could not find a solution, I would be glad if you could help.

I see the response from the web service, but I don't catch an instant update,

```
on: (name, fn) => {
    
    firebase.messaging().onMessage( async( message) => {

        console.log('FCM Message Data:', message.data);
            
        console.log(message)

        //messaging.onMessage(async (message) => {
            
            const command = message.data.command;

            if (command = x =  name) {
            //     const data = JSON.parse(message._data.obj)
            //     console.log("OnMessage_" + command, data);

                if (command == "FavoriEkleCikar") {
                    MirkService.Mirk(data.soruID)
                        .then((d) => {
                            fn(d)
                        })

                } else if (command == "ReMirkEkleCikar") {
                    MirkService.Mirk(data.soruID)
                        .then((d) => {
                            fn(d)
                        })
                }
                else if (command == "MirkCevapla") {
                    MirkService.Mirk(data.soruID)
                        .then((d) => {
                            fn(d)
                        })
                } else if (command == "IddiaSonuc") {
                    MirkService.Mirk(data.soruID)
                        .then((d) => {
                            fn(d)
                        })
                } else if (command == "MirkSil") {
                    fn(data)
                }
                else if (command == "MirkYayinla") {
                    fn()
                }
                else if (command == "TakipAkisTemizleme") {
                    fn(data)
                }
                else if (command == "YeniBildirim") {
                    fn(data)
                }
                else if (command == "Takiplesme") {
                    fn()
                }
                else if (command == "Bloklama") {
                    fn()
                }
                else if (command == "KullaniciGuncellendi") {
                    fn()
                }
                else if (command == "Yorum") {
                    MirkService.Mirk(data.soruID)
                        .then((d) => {
                            fn(d)
                        })
                }
            }
        });
        },
    onNotificationClick: (fn) => {
        
        firebase.messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(notificationOpen => {
            if (notificationOpen && notificationOpen.notification) {
                console.log("onNotificationOpened", notificationOpen);
                fn(notificationOpen.notification);
            }
        });
        firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification().then((notificationOpen) => {
            if (notificationOpen && notificationOpen.notification) {
                console.log("getInitialNotification", notificationOpen);
                fn(notificationOpen.notification);
            }
        });
    },
    Init: () => {

        //messaging();

        // notifications = firebase.notifications();

        firebase.messaging().hasPermission().then(enabled => {
            if (!enabled) {
                messaging().requestPermission();
            }
        });
        firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh((fcmToken) => {
            console.log("RefreshFirebaseToken:", fcmToken);
            UserService.updateFirabaseToken(fcmToken);
        })
        firebase.messaging().getToken().then((fcmToken) => {
            console.log("GetFirebaseToken:", fcmToken);
            UserService.updateFirabaseToken(fcmToken);
        });
        firebase.messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((notification) => {
            notification.android.setChannelId('mirk-channel')
            console.log("onNotification", notification);
       
        firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
                firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
        });;
        });
    }
}

export default FirebaseTool;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors that you could share?